# Como hacer para interactuar con navigation drawer y un fragment al mismo tiempo

Tags: android, studio, navigation

Estoy en un proyecto que se trata de tener una barra lateral (navigation drawer) y me deje abrir varios fragmentos sin que se cierre la navigation drawer. Eso ya lo logré con setdrawermodeopen pero ahora no me deja interactuar con los fragmentos y solo me deja interactuar con los menus de navigation drawer. Mi aplicación debe ser similar a la de la izquierda en la imagen [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, revisa [ask] ,saludos.